# How can i decode and encode this character in python using utf-8?

Tags: python-3.x

suppose if i enter `'f0 a1 88 bd'.decode('utf-8)` i should get the character representing it also the reverse using the `'Japanese character'.encode(utf-8)` to get output `'f0 a1 88 bd'`

The UTF-8 symbol and its corresponding value is shown in https://charbase.com/2123d-unicode-cjk-unified-ideograph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems "\xf0\xa1\x88\xbd" is the code utf-8

I got the same value use [this url](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode)

And convert like this

```
text = ''
print (text.encode('utf-8')) #get  \xf0\xa1\x88\xbd
text2 = text.encode('utf-8')
print (text2.decode('utf-8')) # get
```

There have "\x" before each code  like f0 => \xf0